# Google Adwords API TargetingIdea KEYWORD_TEXT returns trailing numbers

Tags: php, google-ads-api

```php
# sample return data from TargetingIdea following https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/php/optimization#get-keywords-related-to-a-seed-keyword

Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\o\TargetingIdea^ {#2396
  #data: array:5 [
    0 => Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\o\Type_AttributeMapEntry^ {#2441
      #key: "KEYWORD_TEXT"
      #value: Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\o\StringAttribute^ {#2439
        #value: "digital agency thailand ff9d9077"
        #AttributeType: "StringAttribute"
        -parameterMap: array:1 [
          "Attribute.Type" => "AttributeType"
        ]
      }
    }
```

The method of calling for the keyword idea generations are done correctly

```php
        $querySearchParam = new RelatedToQuerySearchParameter();
        $querySearchParam->setQueries($keywords);
        $searchParameters[] = $querySearchParam;

        $relatedUrlSearchParam = new RelatedToUrlSearchParameter();
        $relatedUrlSearchParam->setUrls($urls);
        $searchParameters[] = $relatedUrlSearchParam;

        $languageParam = new LanguageSearchParameter();
        $languageParam->setLanguages([new Language(1000)]);
        $searchParameters[] = $languageParam;

        $networkSearchParam = new NetworkSearchParameter(); 
        $networkSearchParam->setNetworkSetting(new NetworkSetting(true));
        $searchParameters[] = $networkSearchParam;
```

However it returns a randomly generated alphanumeric after the keyword text. Eg: `ff9d9077` at the end of the `KEYWORD_TEXT` attribute `digital agency thailand`. Where the same keyword idea returns multiple times but with different randomly generated trailing alphanumeric text such as `digital agency thailand 13fdc22`, `digital agency thailand c73761c` etc

Anyone can advice what might went wrong on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using an AdWords test account.

Quoting the current Google AdsWord API documentation, under [Managing Accounts | Test accounts | Additional characteristics of test accounts](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/accounts-overview#additional_characteristics_of_test_accounts):

> *The [TargetingIdeaService](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/latest/TargetingIdeaService) and [TrafficEstimatorService](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/latest/TrafficEstimatorService) return dummy data to test accounts.*